# How to avoid dom / Deno type conflicts with Typescript SSR

Tags: typescript, server-side-rendering, deno

I'm trying to set up React SSR using Typescript and Deno based on [this guide](https://www.sanity.io/guides/server-side-rendering-deno-react). The basic setup worked, however when I tried to add the BlueprintJS component library I ran into an issue.

Blueprint depends on [Popper](https://popper.js.org/) which uses some DOM types, e.g. `CSSStyleDeclaration`. My `server.tsx` needs to use the `Deno` object *and* Popper (because it needs to `import { App } from "components/app.tsx";`) so theoretically I need my `tsconfig.json` to contain both Deno and DOM types, like this:

```
"lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext", "deno.ns", "deno.unstable"],
```

However that doesn't work because they conflict with each other. But I need them both - if I remove either then I'll get missing type errors - either for `Deno` or for `CSSStyleDeclaration`.

How can I resolve this without sacrificing type checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can't](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/13564), and you'll need to separately type-check all modules which use incompatible ambient types, then run your program with type-checking disabled.

The TypeScript compiler (which is what Deno currently uses to compile TS source files) isn't yet capable of handling modules in a single graph which rely on conflicting ambient types.

Comment: IMO this is a **huge** PITA, but it's the only way to maintain type-safety.

Comment: How do I type check the `server.tsx` module (which needs Deno) when it imports `app.tsx` (which needs DOM)? Or would you just give up on that?

Comment: @Timmmm That's the part that's simply not possible. You'd have to separate your code into modules by the ambient types that they use as much as possible to preserve type-checking, then skip type-checking for the modules that use conflicting types in the same compilation graph. Functional programming patterns are helpful here (since it's less likely that the public type interfaces of the exports are conflicting, even if they _use_ conflicting types).

Comment: Ah that makes sense, thanks!